# JQuery missing : after property ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am working with some jquery code to do a simple hide of a p and a show of a p. I am simple adding a class called showp and showing it while making sure the others are not shown by hiding them first. But I keep getting an error missing : after property ID. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    $(document).ready({
    $("#phone").click(function(){
        $(".hide2").addClass(".hide2").hide("slow");
        $(".hide3").addClass(".hide3").hide("slow");
        $(".hide1").addClass("showp").show("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: is "showp" a valid css class?

Comment: Probably completely unrelated, but I think you've got too many dots - should be .addclass("hide2") and .addClass("hide3"). Also, why are you adding a class of hide3 to an element that's already got it?

Comment: @brumScouse Actually, you have it the other way around. addClass shouldn't have the . in front of the class name.

Comment: your `$(".hide2").addClass(".hide2")` finds elements with the `hide2` class and tries to add it to them again (*the `.` is invalid also in the addClass method, just use the name*) .. so its really does nothing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
$(document).ready({
```

To this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#phone").click(function() {
      $(".hide2, .hide3").hide();
      $(".hide1").show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your document ready is invalid.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // stuff here.
});
```

Or better yet, a shorthand:

```
$(function() {
  // stuff here.
});
```