# how to validate object in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am adding arbitrary data to li element using jquery as:

```
  if($("li").data('family').$(this).text()==$(this).text()){
        $("li").removeData('family',{'persons':''}); // I know this is wrong!
        // any idea how to remove data from this object 
    }else{
        //this part adds data which is not working fine 
        $("li").data('family',{$(this).text():$(this).text(),
            'cat':'family'
        });
    }
```

above I m trying to validate whether the value already exits or not if exits remove it.
I am facing 1 problem:

1. How to **add / remove** key value same from object

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just `$("li").removeData('family')` doesn't work for you?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/removeData/ and `{$(this).text():$(this).text(), 'cat':'family'}` is a syntax error.

Comment: I know it is But I want to add in that way same key & same value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#cat-family ul li").live("click", function() {
            var $ul = $(this).closest('ul');
            var family = $ul.data('family');
            if (!family) {
                family = {
                    'cat' : 'family'
                };
                $ul.data('family', family);
            }

            var text = $(this).text();
            if (family[text]) {
                delete family[text];
            } else {
                family[text] = text;
            }
            console.log(this, $ul.data().family);
        });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Sct6f/7/)

Comment: I am sorry but I am not storing data person as key

Comment: here you  are adding new key t ,I want $(this).text() both as key & value

Comment: @sandip sorry copy mistake

Comment: what are you trying to acheive here

Comment: while watching demo please check in your firebug!

Comment: if you see the firebug , I m trying to create an object if you click on list it must add to object & if you click it once again it should remove from that object

Comment: Whether the `family` data is shared between all `li`s or each one should have their own `family` object

Comment: I want to store like family{'key','value'} and all numbers 3 to 15 must be added to as family{'3',3} like this on one click & if you click it again it should remove from that list

Comment: the key should be removed?

Comment: let's chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25653/discussion-between-rohan-kumar-and-sandip

Comment: if I click on list of number lets say 3 it will add as family{'3',3} & if I click again on 3 should be either  family{'3',''} or family{//shpuld display other key values if exits}

Comment: Your requirement was very vague, if you said the last requirement initially this was a very easy one

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var key='';
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#cat-family ul li").on("click",function(){
    var $li=$(this);
    key=$(this).text();
    if($(this).data('family')){
        if($(this).data('family').key==$(this).text())
             $(this).removeData('family');        
    }
    else{  
        key=$li.text();
        var k={};
        k[key]=key;
        k['cat']='fam';

        $(this).data('family',k);
    } 
       console.log($(this).data());  
});
});
```

Read Docs http://api.jquery.com/removeData/

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/WmLQa/1/

Comment: missing : after property id

Comment: I changed my answer, for this type of error read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053278/jquery-missing-after-property-id

Comment: I am sorry plz check question again!

Comment: This is again an error , I want to add ->  $(this).text()  as key & value both

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25653/discussion-between-rohan-kumar-and-sandip)

Answer (score 0):

you can check data by:

```
 if($("li").data("family").persons === $(this).text())
 {
     $.removeData($("li") , "family"); //to remove
 }
```

Comment: I am sorry  but I am not storing data person as key

Comment: This  will delete whole object , I want to delete particular key-value